# Woocommerce how to display products from specific category on archive page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On my archive-product page I want to display some products from a specific category.

I tried to do this:

```
echo '<div>';
echo wc_get_product_category_list( 'special_items', $category ));
echo '</div>';
```

inside the product loop, but it doesn't work.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In woocommerce some shortcode available. You may call echo do_shortcode in your template files

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/#scenario-5-specific-categories